# Converter uma data em javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, data

Boa Tarde. Como faço para converter uma data em javaScript, tendo em conta a data introduzida poderá ter o formato dia-mes-ano ou ano-dia-mes. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
data = toDate('2015-10-01');

function toDate(dateStr) {
            dateStr = dateStr.replace('/', '-');
            var parts = dateStr.split("-");
            return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
        }
```

Mas a função não resolve o problema se eu inseri-se a data com os formatos 01-10-2015 ou 01/10/2015.

Que soluções tenho? Obrigado.

Comment: Te aconselho ter somente um tipo de máscara de entrada. Existe algum motivo específico em ter duas máscaras de entrada?

Comment: O ano vai ter sempre 4 caracteres? Por exemplo: 1998 ao invés de 98? Além disso, na pergunta o formato está "ano-dia-mês", o que siginfica que a data de exemplo ali é "10 de Janeiro de 2015". É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se abaixo é o suficiente para você. 
Caso ainda tenha dúvidas, comente.

```js
var st = "26-04-2013";
var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/;
var dt = new Date(st.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));

alert(dt);
```

Comment: Funcionou como eu queria. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Se queres uma função que trabalhe com dia-mes-ano ou ano-dia-mes tens de detetar qual o formato passado.

Uma sugestão:

```
function datar(str) {
    var partes = str.split(/[\/\-]/);
    var date = partes[0].length == 4 ? new Date(partes[0], partes[2], partes[1]) : new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
    return date;
}

console.log(datar('01-10-2015')); // Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
console.log(datar('2015/20/10')); // Fri Nov 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/xqzssh8u/

Comment: Sim. Trabalhar com data requer conhecimento do que realmente precisa. Muito boa sua resposta, está de certa forma mais completa.